# How realistic is Metro 2033

Tags: internal-consistency, post-apocalypse, nuclear

In the universe of Metro 2033 by Dmitri Alexejewitsch Gluchowski the whole world got destroyed in a nuclear war. It's set in the year 2033 and the war was "over 25 years ago". The two original books by him are located in Moscow, other books by other authors are located somewhere else, e. g. Petersburg, Rome,

Here are some facts:

- people are only living in the metro
- the surface is contaminated (except some unimportant places, which wasn't worth to destroy)
- mutants live on the surface (nobody knows where they come from)
- humans only go to the surface to hunt and collect
- ammo is used at currency

I have heard that the metro in Washington was also built as a huge bunker.
But how realistic is the rest?

Edit: can people live on the surface somewhere in Siberia, when all big cities was bombed? Wouldn't be the fallout deadly?

Comment: Welcome to the site Motte.  Realism is kinda subjective when it comes to world building.  We can give guidance on internal consistency and things like that but "realism" is what you want it to be.

Comment: @James let's say "could this happen" instead of realism

Comment: With your edit, your question is now completely unrelated to Metro 2033. Living in Moscow's subway system and living in the cold Siberia are two very different things.

Comment: @Vincent No, the first book of Metro is locatetd in Moscau, other books of other authors in this universe are located in the whole world

Comment: Oh sorry, I just played the game!

Comment: @Vincent there are also stories/legends told by people in Moscow about people in other parts of Russia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is that population density is significantly limited by the hunter-gatherer lifestyle.

Your setting is a major metropolis, so unlikely to have significant populations of standard prey animals. It's set a significant period after the apocalypse event so primary supplies of stored food and water will have been exhausted (not that there's a lot in the metro anyway).

A population up to about 50 could *possibly* survive, but god knows what they're actually living on. Not enough to have an economy or consider having something so crude as a currency, it's communal living, or death.